# I am looking for a library or API to do vector overlay for two map layer (shapefiles or GML files)

Tags: api, overlay, library

I need to perform vector overlay operation on any two map layers as ArcGIS and Grass GIS performs. I am wondering is there any API or library ( in C, C++ or Java) so that I can use that third party library for my GIS project. I am looking forward to find intersection between two map layers using that library.

Answer (score 4):

A couple geometry libraries I'm aware of include:

- Java Topology Suite, [JTS](https://www.tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html)
- Geometry Engine Open Source, [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/)

[OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) provides read/write access to many spatial formats and includes many, if not all, of the spatial operations provided by GEOS.